# Probability $2$ Birthdays are within $m$ Days

Tags: probability

I have a problem which boils down to an extension of the Birthday Problem. If the probability $\bar{p}$ of $2$ out of $n$ people having a birthday within $1$ day of each other in $k$ days is:

$$
\bar{p}(k;n)=\frac{n!\binom{k}{n}}{k^{n}}
$$

What is the probability that $2$ birthdays occur within $m$ days?

---

My intuition tells me it is along the lines of:

$$
\bar{p}(k;n,m)=1\times\left(1-\frac1{k-m+1}\right)\times\left(1-\frac2{k-m+1}\right)\times\cdots\times\left(1-\frac{n-m}{k-m+1}\right).
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be found in the wiki article

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Near_matches

I don't have the derivation of that formula.